Fastlane building error but Android Studio builds just fine
I am getting this error:
Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':sdk:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin'.

Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.

Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

when I run fastlane command do build aok file and send it to the firebase distribution.
When I build signed apk from Android Studio everything works fine. I have three modules and in all of them there are
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}

./gradlew assembleDebug works just fine on other project but on this not.
I tried solution that I fouind online but without success.
